# How can I scan available networks when Wi-Fi is off in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

There is an option added in android 4.3+ as pointed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/101281) that enabled this but is the process exactly the same as scanning when the Wi-Fi is on?

**My question** is how to get all available networks when wifi state is off?

Comment: I feel like this isn't programming related. Should be asked here, maybe  http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: No. I want to do this programmatically!